# Checksum wrong output?

Tags: sql-server, checksum

In Microsoft SQL Server 14

```
print checksum('-test-')
print checksum('-t-e-s-t-')
```

returns the same output:

```
-1854252673
-1854252673
```

What is wrong?

Comment: SQL Server 14 - is this SQL Server **2014**, or do you mean SQL Server **v14** = SQL Server 2017 ?? Please be precise!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `HASHBYTES()` instead of `CHECKSUM()`.

Read this [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/12/09/checksum-and-binary_checksum-might-not-return-unique-values-for-different-inputs/).

Comment: That is a suggestion, not an answer. And one without explanation does not really teach much of anything.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your collation.

On my Computer, collation is French_100_BIN2 and your queries returns :
44180589
1803164231